# Use pretokenized text with lucene

Tags: java, lucene, jruby, tokenize

My data is already tokenized with an external resource and I'd like to use that data within lucene. My first idea would be to join those strings with a `\x01` and use a `WhiteSpaceTokenizer` to split them again. Is there a better idea? (the input is in XML)

As bonus, this annotated data also contains synonyms, how would I inject them (represented as XML tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WhitespaceTokenizer` is unfit for strings joined with `0x01`. Instead, derive from [`CharTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/CharTokenizer.html), overriding `isTokenChar`.

The main problem with this approach is that joining and then splitting again migth be expensive; if it turns to be too expensive, you can implement a trivial `TokenStream` that just emits the tokens from its input.

If by synonyms you mean that a term like "programmer" is expanded to a set of terms, say, {"programmer", "developer", "hacker"}, then I recommend emitting these at the same position. You can use a [`PositionIncrementAttribute`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/PositionIncrementAttribute.html) to control this.

For an example of `PositionIncrementAttribute` usage, see [my lemmatizing `TokenStream`](https://github.com/larsmans/lucene-stanford-lemmatizer/blob/master/src/nl/rug/eco/lucene/EnglishLemmaTokenizer.java) which emits both word forms found in full text and their lemmas at the same position.

Comment: But how do I set the char where WhitespaceTokenizer splits?

Comment: @Tass: my mistake; you should use a custom child class of `CharTokenizer`, not `WhitespaceTokenizer`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene allows you to provide your own stream of tokens to the field, bypassing the tokenization step. To do that you can create your own subclass of TokenStream  implementing incrementToken() and then call field.setTokenStream(new MyTokenStream(yourTokens)):

```
public class MyTokenStream extends TokenStream {
    CharTermAttribute charTermAtt;
    OffsetAttribute offsetAtt;

    final Iterator<MyToken> listOfTokens;

    MyTokenStream(Iterator<MyToken> tokenList) {
        listOfTokens = tokenList;
        charTermAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        offsetAtt = addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if(listOfTokens.hasNext()) {
            super.clearAttributes();
            MyToken myToken = listOfTokens.next();
            charTermAtt.setLength(0);
            charTermAtt.append(myToken.getText());
            offsetAtt.setOffset(myToken.begin(), myToken.end());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For synonyms I would suggest creating a separate field, just don't forget to specify the fields properly when creating queries later.